# How do I future-proof a ZFS bpool when installing Ubuntu? (Novice)

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, zfs

I have limited Ubuntu experience; a previous install of Ubuntu on my wife's laptop resulted in error messages about the ZFS pool being too small frequently and consistently.

I'm going to start from a fresh install: is there a way to set up ZFS so that I don't see these errors? Should I be making the default pool larger, or is there a command or tool I should set up to remove old snapshots and keep the pool from filling up?

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is: do you *need* ZFS? Based on the way the question is written, it seems more like overkill. If you’re not using snapshot replication or regularly rolling back to a previous snapshot, then the default Ext4 file system may be sufficient for your needs 

Comment: A wise question, @matigo, and ultimately I did decide to abandon ZFS, which I was really only trying because it was new and interesting, not because I had a strong use case.